# Is there a way to fix my enumerated value getting the ambiguous error?

Tags: c++

I have an enum `months`:

```
enum months{jan = 1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec};
```

However, when I am trying to use these enum values in an array:

```
int months[12] = { jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec };
```

The problem I am having, is in the Error list I am getting:

> 'oct' is ambiguous
> 'dec' is ambiguous

My guess as to why this is happening is that it is something to do with the words `oct` and `dec`, because when I change the words it gets rid of the error.

Does anyone know a fix for this problem?

I'm also slightly curious as to the reason why this is happening.

Comment: See [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1458097)

Comment: Heres what theyre likely conflicting with: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex

Comment: `oct` (octal) and `dec` (decimal) are part of the standard library used to modify the `basefield` of a stream. As the comment above suggests, it's best to avoid `using namespace std` for this reason among others.

Comment: @heapunderrun I checked out the post, and proceeded to stop using namespace std, however, I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Ahhhh so I was correct to assume it was a problem with the word itself. Thank you all for your help, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The enum is named `months` and the array is named `months`.  A problem known as the [Too Many Daves](https://allpoetry.com/poem/11575842-Too-Many-Daves-by-Theodor-Seuss-Geisel) problem.